# How to select non-header cells with css

Tags: html, css

Given a table like the one below that includes rowspan cells for some row headers, how can I select all of the "row content" cells using only css without changing the HTML markup?

The table is generated such that the rowspan header cells could be on different rows or possibly no rowspan at all, so the css can't be hardcoded to specific row numbers.

Is this possible with only css?

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Header 1</th>
      <th>Column Header 2</th>
      <th>Column Header 3</th>
      <th>Column Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Row Header 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 4</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Row Header 5</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 6</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are rows 3 & 6 deliberately lacking headers or was that an accidental ommission on your part when pasting the code?

Comment: Apologies, I misread the `rowspans` as `colspans` so I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looking at the individual cells, trying to find a consistency between the content cells that would allow you to select only them or a consistency between the header cells that would allow you to select all but them, we should instead look at the entire rows because, when we do so, it is immediately apparent that all the rows containing header cells have a total of 4 cells, while those that don't only have 3.

Armed with that knowledge, we can target the content cells only by combining the [negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) to select every cell bar the 4th last one in each row, like so:

```
td:not(:nth-last-child(4)){}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is semantically incorrect:

1. Use [`<th>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element) for header cells
2. Use [`<td>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element) for data cells
3. Then you can select data cells with `td` CSS selector.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Header 1</th>
      <th>Column Header 2</th>
      <th>Column Header 3</th>
      <th>Column Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row Header 1</th>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Row Header 2</th>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row Header 4</th>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Row Header 5</th>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row Header 6</th>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have changed the HTML. I am looking for a css only solution as I do not have access to change the html markup of the table.

Comment: Then you can try `:nth-child`, but to do it properly you would need to parse the `rowspan` attributes, and CSS can't do that. If only a small subset of values is allowed, you could hardcode it, but it would be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the attribute selector:

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

td[rowspan] {
  background: lightBlue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Header 1</th>
      <th>Column Header 2</th>
      <th>Column Header 3</th>
      <th>Column Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Row Header 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 4</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Row Header 5</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 6</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or a combination of the `not` selector and attribute selector depending on what you are trying to acheieve:

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

td:not([rowspan]) {
  background: lightBlue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Header 1</th>
      <th>Column Header 2</th>
      <th>Column Header 3</th>
      <th>Column Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Row Header 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 4</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Row Header 5</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Header 6</td>
      <td>Row Content 1</td>
      <td>Row Content 2</td>
      <td>Row Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to select only the row content cells, these options are selecting some row header cells.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread. If the only thing that defines a "row header" is it's content then what you want is simply not possible with CSS.